# how to use windows phone 8 c# list in jQuery function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, windows-phone-8

i want to build accordion menu in windows phone browser control. for that i am parsing one rest-service and put it in a list. now i want to access that list in my html page jQuery function. for that i am  using the below code but i am not able to read the list values in my jQuery function.

**Code:**

```
private void browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{      
    List<string> str = new List<string>();
    str.Add("Welcome");
    str.Add("Bye");
    browser.InvokeScript("getMemoryUsageCallback", str.ToArray());
}
```

**HTML Page**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#accordian h1").click()
                {

                }


            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="accordion">
      <h3 id="memoryUsageLimit">Section 1</h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
        amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
        odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
      </div>
      <h3>Section 2</h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
        purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
        velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
        suscipit faucibus urna.
        </p>
      </div>
      <h3>Section 3</h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
        Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
        ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
        lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>List item one</li>
          <li>List item two</li>
          <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h3>Section 4</h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
        et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
        faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
        mauris vel est.
        </p>
        <p>
        Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
        inceptos himenaeos.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

         <script type="text/javascript">
             function onLoad() {
                 window.external.notify("getMemoryUsage");
             }

             $(function getMemoryUsageCallback(str1) {


                 $(accordion).append("<h3>"+str1.valueOf[0] +"</h3>");
                 $(accordion).accordion();
             });
        </script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

but i am getting The str[0] value as undefined. please help me out in solving this problem.

and also post some example project links where i can use C#, JavaScript, and J-query in windows phone mobile app in web-browser control. and also any examples of accessing C# variables in  Javascript and jquery vice-versa.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, try post your full html.

Comment: i posted the full html page. check once now.

Comment: First, str1.valueOf[0] -- this is wrong. Assuming you pass array of strings you should use just str1[0] for example. I see in comment that str[0] is undefined, but str != str1; Second, wrapping your getMemoryUsageCallback in $() binds this named function to body onload event, so it will run on page load without any arguments passed through, but you want to invoke it on browser_ScriptNotify. You need to make client code more logical and it probably will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are not calling `onLoad()`. It's not going to be magically invoked. Update your body tag to

```html
<body onload="onLoad();">
```

Also change your `getMemoryUsageCallback` function as follows

```js
function getMemoryUsageCallback() {
    $(accordion).append("<h3>" + arguments[0] + "</h3>");
    $(accordion).accordion();
}
```

You can access `arguments` built-in variable to access passed args. Also including `$(function ... });` will cause an error so just use normal js function declaration as I shown above.

Full html follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#accordian h1").click()
            {

            }


        });

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad();">

<div id="accordion">
  <h3 id="memoryUsageLimit">Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         function onLoad() {
             window.external.notify("getMemoryUsage");
         }

         function getMemoryUsageCallback() {
             $(accordion).append("<h3>" + arguments[0] + "</h3>");
             $(accordion).accordion();
         }
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still it is not working.if i remove $(function}); the function is not getting called.

Comment: I just checked, working fine. I am including full html in my post, a new accordion tab should be added with the label 'Welcome'. See my edit

Comment: Thank u so much for your help. can you post any example project links which will use c# and java-script in web-browser control.                  Tell me the best way of doing mobile Web Application using c# and javascript.

Comment: I don't have any links atm, I'll add here if I see any.

Comment: k thank u. if you know any tutorials or sample projects let me know